# Win7 application hang (event ID 1002) - definition of "Termination Time"

Tags: event-log

One of my C# apps reportedly hung up. In the application event log I can see it is logged under event ID 1002 with below details.

My question is about the statement "Termination Time". What is its definition, and in which unit?

```
The program ****.exe version 1.0.0.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
Process ID: ****
Start Time: ****
Termination Time: 17
Application Path: ****
Report Id: ****
```

Kind regards,
Jorg

Comment: Compare the start time to the time the even was written and check whenever one of the common units makes sense?

Comment: The "start time" (once converted in Powershell) exactly matches the time that the process executable was started (several days before the crash event happened), so that does not correlate to the value "17".

I wonder if the "termination time" could be the time between the UI message "not responding" and the moment that the user clicks "Close program"?